# Remove the add new item from wordpress but allow editing

Tags: wordpress, function

I have this code that removes pages from users that are not admin on a site I developing.

```
function remove_menu_items() {
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=hp_slides' );
    remove_menu_page( 'post-new.php?post_type=foodswaps' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
```

However the bottom remove item doesn't work, the post type is correct but the sub menu item still remains. Can any one see what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem a couple weeks ago!

So you are trying to remove a submenu item, therefore need to use something like this:

```
function remove_menu_items() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        // remove new post button from the food swaps custom post type if not admin
        $page = remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=foodswaps', 'post-new.php?post_type=foodswaps' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items' );
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks! never occured to me that it was a submenu and not a menu page item :-/